# Laravel Wont Write to Directory

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel wont write to my directory.

the error i get is.

```
ErrorException

Unable to write in the "/var/www/laravel/laravel/public/img/retailer_images/12/" directory (View: /var/www/laravel/laravel/app/views/edit_retailer.blade.php)
```

the file "img" is owend by ubuntu:www-data and the has the permissions of 0777.

i am sure i am missing something simple.

the input code is, (I know this works as it works on other deployed servers)

```
    if  (file_exists    ('/img/retailer_images/$retailer_id/banner.png')    )   {
            unlink('/img/product_images/$retailer_id/banner.png');          
        }
        $file                = Input::file('image');
        $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" )
            {
            $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            }
        else if($extension=="png")
            {
            $src = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            }
        else 
            {
            $src = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            }
        list($width,$height) = getimagesize($file);
        $tmp                 = imagecreatetruecolor("600","162");
        $force_resize        = imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,"600","162", $width, $height);
        $destinationPath     = public_path().'/img/retailer_images/'.$retailer_id.'/';
        $filename            = "banner.png";
        $uploadSuccess       = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
        $new_file_dest       = $destinationPath.$filename;
        DB::table('retailers')->where('id', $retailer_id)->update(array('retailer_img_url' => "http://sniip-kinetic-env-dqcu3vmfku.elasticbeanstalk.com/img/retailer_images/$retailer_id/banner.png"));
// TO DO add user friendly message here displayed with the image they just uploaded in a thumb size (300 X 300)     
        echo "<img src=/img/retailer_images/$retailer_id/banner.png height=162 width=600> </img><br />";
        echo "file uploaded";
    }
```

Comment: Check directly if dir is writable doing `File::isWritable('path')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, don't have enough rep to comment:

What does your app/storage/logs/laravel.log say? as well as your /var/logs/-webservername-/error_log ?

also make sure that your Apache/nginx runs under www-data
..

Another thing:

try

```
('/img/retailer_images/$retailer_id/banner.png')
```

with double quotes 
and like this:

```
("/img/retailer_images/{$retailer_id}/banner.png")
```

Comment: there is no log info telling me any more errors it just keep telling me it cant wirte

Comment: is your logging errors enabled in php.ini? also do you have "debug" = true, in laravel app.php ?

Answer (score 0):

This was a true obscure issue, the problem was there was corrupt data in the file ..../img/12/ named banner.png that could not be over written (Pems issue) i removed it from the git repository pushed up then pulled to the remote. then i pressed good 'ol F5 and it all worked perfect Thanks for help on this.